# How do I highlight a word starting with '<>' on first backspace and delete the same on a second backspace in a content editable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, contenteditable

```js
const textareaHtml = `
  <div class="textarea-item">
    <div class="edit" role="textbox" contenteditable="true" id="${textareaId}">
    </div>
    <ul class="autocomplete-list"></ul>
  </div>`;
$(".textarea-container").append(textareaHtml);
```

I have an app which takes notes and you can reference another note by typing '<>' which opens a dropdown of other notes i can add. Basically i want to be able to delete the entire thing ("<>notes") by highlighting it first and deleting it later. how would i achieve this for a contenteditable div.Found the answer for a textarea but couldnt get the cursor and highlighting for this. Thank you.

I tried using caretposition and couldnt find the substitute for selectstart and end as in textarea.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Assuming 'textareaId' is the ID of your contenteditable div
const contenteditableDiv = document.getElementById(textareaId);

// Function to select a range of text within a contenteditable div
function selectText(start, end) {
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(contenteditableDiv.firstChild, start);
  range.setEnd(contenteditableDiv.firstChild, end);
  
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
}

// Function to delete the currently selected text
function deleteSelectedText() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
    selection.deleteFromDocument();
  }
}

// Add an event listener to the contenteditable div
contenteditableDiv.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  if (event.key === 'Backspace' || event.key === 'Delete') {
    deleteSelectedText();
  }
});

// Example usage: select and delete text from 10th to 20th character
selectText(10, 20);
deleteSelectedText();
```

source: chat-gpt

Comment: The snippet is broken when you click "Run snippet". `Uncaught ReferenceError: textareaId is not defined` - You should probably include the right HTML!